# python library to manage kafka cluster (topics CRUD, increase partition, reassignment, leader election etc)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I searched in internet for python library to manage kafka operations like CRUD on topics, partition increment, partition reassignment, leader election etc. I didn't find anything.

I know pykafka, kafka-python, but they are for creating consumers/producers, i can use kazoo for CRUD on topics, but i can't perform other operations i mentioned. can you suggest any python library for managing kafka cluster (if available) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PyKafka includes a CLI for creating topics [here](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/blob/a4b6793c655d10d6edfc705445ca11dd07692f70/pykafka/cli/kafka_tools.py#L265). I'm not sure what you mean by "partition increment". The assignment of partitions to consumers is handled internally by PyKafka's membership protocol implementations. Leader election is, to my knowledge, not triggerable by clients.

I don't know of a python library that fully replicates the functionality of the CLI tools that come bundled with Kafka, but PyKafka comes close.

Comment: Thanks for answer. partition increment means changing number of partitions assigned to a topic. my bad, i was not mention clearly.